# How do I check Duplicate

Tags: c#

```
private void Add_Box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string phoneNumber;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id_Box.Text))// To check if the Id_box is empty or not
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your ID");// need to enter ID in order to save data
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////check the Extension Box////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    else
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Ext_Box.Text))
        {
            phoneNumber = Phone_Box.Text;// if it is empty then it will only show the phone number
        }
        else
        {

            phoneNumber = Phone_Box.Text + "," + Ext_Box.Text; // show the phone number and the extension if there is something in the extension
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Save it to the Database///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Contact_List(Id, Name, Adress1, Adress2, City, Province, Postal_Code, Phone, Email)VALUES('" + Id_Box.Text + "','" + Name_Box.Text + "','" + Adress1_Box.Text + "','" + Adress2_Box.Text + "','" + City_Box.Text + "','" + Province_Box.Text + "','" + Code_Box.Text + "','" + phoneNumber + "','" + Email_Box.Text + "')", con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Information Added", "Confirm");
        /////////////////////////////////////Show new set of data after insert a new data/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////              
        SqlCeCommand cmd2 = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from Contact_List;", con);
        try
        {
            SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd2;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            sda.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        ////////////////////////////////Empty The Box/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Id_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Name_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Adress1_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Adress2_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        City_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Province_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Code_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Phone_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Ext_Box.Text = String.Empty;
        Email_Box.Text = String.Empty;
    }

}
```

This code will store Id, name, etc to the database. But when there is a same Id, i want to delete it. When i delete it both of the same Id will be deleted and i don't want that so is there anyway to check duplicate before it store it to the database?

I want to do something like this if possible :

```
if ( the values in id column == to the Id_textBox) {
    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate ,PLease enter anotherId")
}
```

Possible?

Comment: instead of emptying all of the boxes by setting them to string.Empty, why don't you use a foreach loop or linq to check if the type is TextBox then set the textbox.Text to string.Empty for example 
`yourForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());`

Comment: also why don't you do a check of the id for example Select Count(*) From table where Id = @Id parameter.. if count > 1 then display the Duplicate before allowing the Insert...

Comment: you've essentially asked the same question a couple days ago, with less code. Did you consider using google instead of stackoverflow? Your answer is out there on the internet in a couple thousand of versions. Finding the answer yourself is usually faster than waiting a couple days for someone to do your homework

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your `INSERT` SQL statement, try running the SQL `int ContactCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CONTACT_LIST WHERE Id = '" + Id_Box.Text + "'")`

If `ContactCount > 0` then you can do the DELETE your suggesting.

Can I also recommend that you use a SQL UPDATE instead of DELETEing and INSERTing the same record.

Also, read-up on SQL Injection attacks.  Building a SQL statement, like you're doing here, using the values input by a user leaves you exposed to that type of vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like in all these answers: Don't use string concatenation but parametrized queries to prevent SQL-injection.

For your problem:

You can either do a

```
string query = "SELECT count(*) from ContactList Where id = @id";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Id_Box.Text;
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

if `count > 0` the id already exists.

Or you can do a

```
string query "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT count(*) from ContactList Where id = @id) INSERT INTO ContactList(Id, ...) VALUES(@id, ...)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Id_Box.Text;
int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`count` will then contain the number of rows affected, ie `0` if the value already existed, or `1` if it did not exist, but was newly inserted.